# Не определяет значение активной ячейки... App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

Суть в том, что не определяет значение активной ячейки... не могу понять в чем проблема... вместо этого определяет ячейку А1 и всегда дает информацию о ней. Хочу из активной ячейки достать цвет и содержимое... но не получается... помогите((

```
function cellTester() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  var RGB = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getBackgroundObject().asRgbColor().asHexString();
  Logger.log(activeCell);
  var status = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Список команды").getRange(2, 1, 5, 1).getValues();
  
  var chatID = "мой айди" 
  var ipTokken =  "Мой токей";
  var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + ipTokken + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chatID + "&text=" + "салам пополам";
 

  
  Logger.log(status);
  Logger.log(RGB);
```

Comment: А запускается этот скрипт в каком контексте? Может это webApp? Или просто скрипт в таблице?

Comment: Просто скрипт в таблице

Answer (score 0):

Oпечатка в 4-й строке.

Вместо `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet()`

должно быть просто `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` .

Да, `SpreadsheetApp` может сразу получать активный лист активной таблицы.

Работающий код ниже:

```
function cellTester() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet       = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var activeCell  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  var RGB         = spreadsheet.getActiveCell().getBackgroundObject().asRgbColor().asHexString();

  Logger.log(activeCell);

  var status      = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Список команды").getRange(2, 1, 5, 1).getValues();
  var chatID      = "мой айди" 
  var ipTokken    = "Мой токей";
  var url         = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + ipTokken + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chatID + "&text=" + "салам пополам";
  
  Logger.log(status);
  Logger.log(RGB);
}
```